# hash_add crashes the system

Tags: c, linux, kernel, hashtable

When I'm adding an element to my hash table it crashes the system kernel and I can't figure out the cause of it.

I'm writing some code to do some network packet sniffing in kernel mode and store statistic information in a struct about each packet flow passing my sniffer.

My hash table is defined with:

```
DEFINE_HASHTABLE(flow_dictionary, 10);
```

and later initialized with:

```
hash_init(flow_dictionary);
```

my data structure is defined with

```
struct flow_action_head {
    unsigned int flowID;

    /* Mode of operations */
    SELECTION_MODE sampling_mode;
    SELECTION_MODE normalization_mode;

    /* Statistics */
    unsigned int numberPackets;
    unsigned int timeFirstPacket;
    unsigned int timeLastPacket;
    unsigned int packetsReceived;
    unsigned int packetsProcessed;

    /* Pointer to action details */
    nas_t* next;

    /* Required for linked hash list */
    struct hlist_node hash_list;

}; // __attribute__((packed));
```

In the function I do:

```
void map_add_flow(unsigned int flowID) {

    struct flow_action_head* fah;

    fah = (struct flow_action_head*) kzalloc(sizeof(struct flow_action_head), GFP_ATOMIC);

    fah->flowID = flowID;
    fah->sampling_mode = SMODE_COUNT_BASED;
    fah->normalization_mode = NMODE_TTL;
    fah->numberPackets = 1;
    fah->timeFirstPacket = 0;
    fah->timeLastPacket = 0;
    fah->packetsReceived = 0;
    fah->packetsProcessed = 0;
    fah->next = NULL;

    hash_add(flow_dictionary, &fah->hash_list, flowID);
}
```

as soon as I hit the `hash_add` the system crashes.

I would expect that it just adds the record to the hash table `flow_dictionary` using the `flowID` as the key. I can not see why it would crash it this point. The structure seems to be ok and I can read/write each value of the `flow_action_head` struct.

Comment: If it crashed, then you would have a reason and a stack trace displayed on the console.

Comment: Why are you doing this in kernel mode instead of using `pcap`?

Comment: **Sidenote**: By packing the `struct` you might be encountering unaligned memory access, which (depending on your CPU) could crash the system. Note that you have an un-even number of `int` elements, making it likely for the `next` pointer to be unaligned on 64bit systems.

Comment: You're missing definitions for the `DEFINE_HASHTABLE` macro, `struct hlist_node`, and `hash_add`.  [Edit] your question to make it a [mre].  Does it crash before the call to `hash_add` is made, or does it get into the function, then crash?

Comment: @stark - as this is part of a LKM it loads into kernel mode. When it crashes there is no output anymore to the console or the dmesg log in Linux.

Comment: @Barmar - Not sure I fully understand your point. I only know pcap for packet tracing to files I can store the captured packets for offline use. As I'm doing this on live traffic I'm not sure how I can leverage pcap here. Sorry, when I miss your point here.

Comment: `libpcap` is a library for doing packet capturing. Saving the data to a file is just one of the things you can do with the captured packets.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - 'DEFINE_HASHTABLE', 'struct hlist_node' and 'hash_add' are part of the linux kernel header files ( '/include/linux/hashtable.h' and '/include/linux/types.h' ). 

It crashes when it gets into the 'hash_add' function. When I comment that line out the code runs without any issues (except its not doing what I need it to do).

Comment: @Barmar - I see. thanks for the clarification on `libpcap`. I've just taken another route in the form of using existing hooks in the netfilter bridge module to get my hands on network packets in form of the `skb_buffs`.

Comment: The reason of the crash could be in your **other code**, which you don't show us. This is not a rare in the Linux kernel programming to write some code in a wrong way, but it will work OK... until some other code hits "completely different memory location" Please, provide [mcve].

Comment: Do you get anything displayed on the console when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know your background, so I assume the least.

Are you familiar with kgdb?  If not, you might want to introduce yourself.

I have frequently seen reports “it crashes when I call this function”; and after a tour in the debugger, it turns out that “when I call" means +- a few thousand interrupts and millions of opcodes.  You need to set a breakpoint on the return from the hash_add().

If you aren’t ready to dig into kgdb; you can start with a printk() after this call; the existence of that message provides important clues:
1.  Did you actually crash before hash_add returned or not?   If you can see your message, you definitely made it back from the insertion.
2.  If you made it back, you will have a timestamp from your call which you can compare to the timestamp of when the kernel crashed.

Typically the kernel crashes with more information than “I crashed”.  Sometimes it says where it crashed, the cause of the crash, the stack trace of where it was executing.  All of this information is useful in determining what the root cause of the crash was.

FWIW; looking at the code you posted, I can’t see anything wrong.   I stepped through the hash-stuff, it seems you are using it alright.  I suspect you should look at the point where you remove or lookup things from this hash list.  Good luck, and happy hunting.